# Child of a ViewChild as Component reference

Tags: angular

I have a 3rd party component that has another child component nested inside it.  How can I get the reference as a component instance?  I don't want a nativeElement or ElementRef reference, I know how to get that.

```
<parent>
  <some-child>
    <another-child>
    </another-child>
 </some-child>
```

In my parent I have:

```
 @ViewChild(SomeChildComponent) someChild: SomeChild;
```

the above works fine, but I need to get a reference to AnotherChildComponent.  Note, I don't have the ability to modify the sources for SomeChild, otherwise this would be trivial.  I need to query for the nested child from my parent.  It looks like ViewChild/ViewChildren only queries for immediate children and ContentChild is only for transcluded content so that does not help.

Comment: @ViewChild( AnotherChildComponent) anotherChild: AnotherChild;

Comment: "This means that queries done using @ViewChild can only see elements inside the template of the component itself" source: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-viewchild/